# Angularjs se puede integrar con paymentez

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap, api, web

necesito ayuda con ejemplo con la integración del api paymetez y angularjs.

Al realizar la llamada al api me devuelve error en el callback, segui el tutorial que indica en la referencia de desarrollo.

https://developers.paymentez.com/docs/payments/

Comment: talvez lo pudiste integrar paymentez con angular?

Comment: Hola Christian, deberías añadir más información a tu pregunta: el código que lleves, el error concreto que recibes... Sin ver el código y sin saber qué error te da o dónde, es imposible saber qué e slo que está fallando. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.